# Ao clickar em link realizar reload em div com Angular. ng-click, ng-include, controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directives

Olá! Tenho este link:

```
<ul class="nav child_menu">
    <li><a href="graficos.html">Gráficos</a></li>
</ul>
```

Ao clickar no link deve exibir o `grafico.html` através do `ng-include`:

```
<div ng-include="'graficos.html'"></div>
```

graficos.html:

```
<div ng-controller="graficoCtrl">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <div class="x_panel">
                <div class="x_title">
                    <h2>Line graph<small>Sessions</small></h2>
                    <ul class="nav navbar-right panel_toolbox">
                    //... mais código ...
```

Como visto acima, existe um `controller` (graficoCtrl) e este carrega um gráfico na tag canvas no arquivo `grafico.html`.

```
app.controller('graficoCtrl', function($scope){
    Chart.defaults.global.legend = {
        enabled: false
    };
    // mais código....
```

O que realmente quero fazer é manter a interatividade em uma unica página, ou seja, clicando em um **link**, na mesma página, ocorre um **reload** em uma determinada **div**. Uma Single Page Application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para isso você pode usar ngRoute (existe o angular-ui-router, mas este é mais complexo).

Além da referência no script:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-route.min.js"></script>
```

Você referência como dependência em sua aplicação:

```
angular.module('app',['ngRoute']);
```

Configura as rotas:

```
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
        templateUrl : 'app/views/home.html',
        controller     : 'HomeCtrl',
   });
};
```

Usa a tag `<div ng-view></div>`
e os links com hash `<a href="#/home">Home</a>`

Fonte: http://tableless.com.br/criando-uma-aplicacao-single-page-com-angularjs/